# Different Control in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I don't understand.

What is the difference between "WPF Custom Control Library" and "WPF User Control Library"? what is the pros and cons.

Comment: check [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/179442/So-what-s-the-difference-between-a-Custom-Control) link